# S3 vs DynamoDB for Static content

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, web, amazon-s3

I have a requirement to display Terms and Condition for Order fulfillment to consumers purchasing products on my web portal. Since T&C is a Static content that rarely changes, I am planning to store this file in the AWS S3 bucket. I can pull the static content at runtime using Spring Rest API and display it in the user's web browser, or present it in some other format. I want to know your views about using S3 for this use case? Another option is to use DynamoDB.. but S3 seems to be simple to use.

Comment: For static content, I would probably go with S3 as well. On top of S3, my recommendation is to put an "Amazon CloudFront" and using CF link in the code to fetch S3 static content, instead of exposing S3 links in code. DynamoDB is more like a cache for key/value store and is good when u need to search from lot of data.

Comment: Where are your other web pages and other static content like images, css etc?

Answer (score 1):

If your frontend is hosting on S3, I would suggest you upload your T&C to S3 as well.

But if you are rendering webpage from the application (e.g. Spring), then I suggest you put them on DynamoDB.